# Why is RVM stuck on "#importing default gemsets, this may take time"?

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm

This is displayed in my terminal session when I install Ruby using RVM:

```
ks@ks-mba ~ $ rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr
Removing /Users/ks/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p429... - using ZSH, can not show progress, be patient...
Removing /Users/ks/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429... - using ZSH, can not show progress, be patient...
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/ks/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p429 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p429, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p429 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p429 to /Users/ks/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p429 - using ZSH, can not show progress, be patient...
ruby-1.9.3-p429 - #extracted to /Users/ks/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p429
ruby-1.9.3-p429 - #configuring - using ZSH, can not show progress, be patient...
ruby-1.9.3-p429 - #compiling - using ZSH, can not show progress, be patient...
ruby-1.9.3-p429 - #installing  - using ZSH, can not show progress, be patient...
Retrieving rubygems-1.8.25
Extracting rubygems-1.8.25 ...
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-1.8.25 for ruby-1.9.3-p429.....................
Installation of rubygems completed successfully.
Saving wrappers to '/Users/ks/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p429'...........
 - using ZSH, can not show progress, be patient...
ruby-1.9.3-p429 - #adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
ruby-1.9.3-p429 - #importing default gemsets, this may take time - using ZSH, can not show progress, be patient...
```

The installation just stopped here.

Comment: It just says `be patient` !

Comment: More than five hours left, it's still there.

Comment: That's a long time, just kill it and try again maybe ?

Comment: I have tried three times.

Comment: open an issue for rvm => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Comment: Couple more trials helped me, if it hangs more than 5 mins -> retry

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It hangs forever. However I was behind a proxy with proxy stuff set correctly but it seems the gemset import requires another setting. I solved by switching to a non-proxy wifi during installation. After that it continues immediately.